# Counting vectors and triangles in $\mathbb{Z}^3$

Tags: vectors, triangles, integers

Consider the set $V$ of vectors $\mathbf v$ in 3D space, starting at the origin (of coordinates $(0,0,0)$) and pointing at points in $\mathbb Z^3$.
The square of the length of each such vector is $v^2 = \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v$, which is a non-negative integer in $\mathbb N$.
Let me define the number of unique vectors $\mathbf v \in V$ such that $v^2 = n$ as
$$
N_\nearrow (n) = \sum_{\mathbf v \in V} \delta_K(v^2-n),
$$
where I have introduced the Kronecker delta $\delta_K(x)$, which is $1$ when $x = 0$, and $0$ otherwise.
$N_\nearrow (n)$ is clearly linked to [this integer sequence](https://oeis.org/A005875), since the $n$-th term of the sequence is equal to $N_\nearrow (n)$.

Now, take a triplet of vectors $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2, \mathbf v_3 \in V$. Let me define a "triangle" as a triplet of $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2, \mathbf v_3 \in V$ such that $\mathbf v_1+ \mathbf v_2+ \mathbf v_3 =0$.

Given $n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb N$, is it possible to count the number of triangles $N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ such that $n_1 = v_1^2$, $n_2 = v_2^2$, and $n_3 = v_3^2$, without computing directly all possible (and relevant) combinations of triplets of vectors in $V$ (which might be otherwise numerically expensive in any sort of computation)? Is there a "closed form" or something similar to compute the quantity:
$$
N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3) = \sum_{\mathbf v_1 \in V} \sum_{\mathbf v_2 \in V} \sum_{\mathbf v_3 \in V} \delta_K(v_1^2-n_1) \delta_K(v_2^2-n_2) \delta_K(v_3^2-n_3) \delta_\bigtriangleup(\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2+\mathbf v_3),
$$
where $\delta_\bigtriangleup(\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2+\mathbf v_3)$ is $1$ if $\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2+\mathbf v_3 = 0$, and $0$ otherwise?

What I have so far is this:

- necessary condition to form a triangle is that $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 \equiv 0 \;(\rm mod\, 2)$, therefore all other combinations will give $N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3) = 0$
- $N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ is non-zero only for some values of integer $n_3$ such that $(\sqrt{n_1} - \sqrt{n_2})^2 \le n_3 \le (\sqrt{n_1} + \sqrt{n_2})^2$
- $N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ is completely symmetric in the exchange of the arguments
- if $n_3 = 0$, then $n_1 = n_2$; the only way to form a triangle (albeit degenerate) is then having $\mathbf v_2 = -\mathbf v_1$, and therefore $N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_1, 0) = N_\nearrow (n_1)$
- for any pair $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2 \in V$ there is always one and only one $\mathbf v_3 \in V$ such that $\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2+ \mathbf v_3 = 0$; therefore,
  $$
  \sum_{n_3}N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3) = N_\nearrow (n_1) N_\nearrow (n_2);
  $$
  moreover, for any $\mathbf v_2$ there is one and only one opposite $\tilde {\mathbf v}_2 = -\mathbf v_2$, therefore the third vector closing the triangle would be $\tilde {\mathbf v}_3 = \mathbf v_2 - \mathbf v_1$, $\tilde v_3^2 = 2(v_1^2 + v_2^2) - v_3^2$, and thus $N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, n_3) = N_\bigtriangleup(n_1, n_2, 2(n_1+n_2)-n_3)$

As an example, take $n_1 = n_2 = 1$; then $n_3 = 0, 2, 4$ and I have
$$
N_\nearrow (1) ^2  = 36 = N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 0) + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 2) + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 4) = \\
2 N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 0) + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 2) = 2 \cdot N_\nearrow (1) + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 2) = 2 \cdot 6 + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 2),
$$
which implies $N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 0) = N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 4) = 6$ and $N_\bigtriangleup(1, 1, 2) = 24$.

With a similar approach, $n_1 = 1$ and $n_2 = 2$ gives
$$
72 = N_\bigtriangleup(1, 2, 1) + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 2, 3) + N_\bigtriangleup(1, 2, 5),
$$
and $N_\bigtriangleup(1, 2, 1) = N_\bigtriangleup(1, 2, 3) = N_\bigtriangleup(1, 2, 5) = 24$.

All these values coincide with the ones found by computing directly all the combinations of triplets.

While in these examples this appears to work, in some other cases these conditions do not appear to be enough, however (e.g, take $n_1 = n_2 = 2$). Am I missing something that can help me in solving this problem? And actually, is there even a solution?

Comment: Line number 4: "the number of **unique** vectors" : could you explain what you mean by "unique" in this context, maybe by an example ?

Comment: You are right, it is not very clear, sorry about that. I'd say that, since each vector points to a point in $\mathbb Z^3$, vectors are equal if their tips are on the same point. Points of coordinates (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (-1,0,0), (0,-1,0), and (0,0,-1) would all be different and would correspond to unique vectors, even though they have the same length. For triplets of vectors, I'd say that two triplets are the same if the three vectors are the same **in order** (given a triplet, exchanging two vectors of the triplet gives a different triplet). I hope this makes more sense.